# How to effectively create and link Individual record after Contact is created?

Tags: process-builder, gdpr, consent-management

As we know, Salesforce is expanding the data model for `Consent Management` and `Individual` is one of the key objects here. Do you have any recommended approach on how to create and link Individual to Contact whenever Contact is created? Is Process Builder the way to go? We're moving from previous CRM to Salesforce, so I don't have much hands-on experience yet, but I'm trying to prepare in advance. So the goal is to have the connection between Contact and Individual just after Contact is created, so the Consents can be managed on Individual level.

Comment: as a general remark, eschew Process Builder in favor of Flow as that is the direction of SFDC declarative automation tools

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be by implementing the entire functionality using the visual Flows.